# Function.prototype.bind with arguments object

Tags: javascript, node.js

say I have this simple situation:

```
const f = function(){

 const fn = f.bind(null, arguments);

}
```

I am trying to implement a "retry" mechanism - this code checks out according to the static analysis and seems to the signature of `Function.prototype.bind`, but my question is:

is `arguments` going to be applied as simply the first argument to `f` or will it be spread out, as in, `f.apply(null, arguments)`? I am having trouble finding an example of this online.

Comment: `const fn = f.bind(null, ...arguments);` to spread

Comment: Use `f.apply.bind(f, null, arguments)` or `f.bind.apply(f, [null, ...arguments])`

Comment: Since you're on node.js, use ES6! `function f(...args) { const fn = () => f(...args); }`

Comment: yeah I have seen the spread operator work with arguments, but for some reason I had to do `...Array.from(arguments)`...not sure why.

Comment: @Bergi the example in question is a way oversimplified situation, as it should be...want to see the real thing? :) https://github.com/sumanjs/suman/blob/feature_alexamil_1509956540678/lib/test-suite-helpers/make-handle-test.ts#L88

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.bind` works similar to `.call`, not `.apply` - the second argument will be treated as just that, the second argument. So in your example:

`f(1,2,3)` would produce `fn([1,2,3])`

Answer (score 2):

`arguments` will be passed as simply the first argument to `f`. Moreover, if you then call the bound function with more arguments, those arguments will come after the bound one (i.e. you cannot overwrite that first argument).

read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: Link doesn't seem ok.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, so `Function.prototype.bind` has similar signature to `Function.prototype.call`

so you need to do:

```
fn.bind(null, ...arguments);
```

or

```
fn.bind(null, ...Array.from(arguments));
```